# Calculate time in C language

Tags: c

I am trying to calculate time in C language and i have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int hours, minutes;
    double diff;
    time_t end, start;
    struct tm times;
    times.tm_sec = 0;
    times.tm_min = 0;
    times.tm_hour = 0;
    times.tm_mday = 1;
    times.tm_mon = 0;
    times.tm_year = 70;
    times.tm_wday = 4;
    times.tm_yday = 0;

    time_t ltt;
    time(&ltt);

    struct tm *ptm = localtime(&ltt);
    times.tm_isdst = ptm->tm_isdst;

    printf("Start time (HH:MM): ");

    if((scanf("%d:%d", &times.tm_hour, &times.tm_min)) != 2){
        return 1;
    }

    start = mktime(&times);
    printf("End time (HH:MM): ");

    if((scanf("%d:%d", &times.tm_hour, &times.tm_min)) != 2){
        return 1;
    }
    end = mktime(&times);

    diff = difftime(end, start);
    hours = (int) diff / 3600;
    minutes = (int) diff % 3600 / 60;
    printf("The difference is %d:%d.\n", hours, minutes);
    return 0;
}
```

The program works almost ok:

Output 1:

> ```
> ./program 
> Start time (HH:MM): 05:40
> End time (HH:MM): 14:00
> The difference is 8:20.
> ```

Output 2:

> ```
> ./program 
> Start time (HH:MM): 14:00
> End time (HH:MM): 22:20
> The difference is 8:20.
> ```

Output 3:

> ```
> /program 
> Start time (HH:MM): 22:20
> End time (HH:MM): 05:40
> The difference is -16:-40.
> ```

As you can see, I got **-16:-40** instead of 7:20.

I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Comment: you're doing date math, but haven't added anything to handle crossing a day barrier. sicne your start time is 22 (10pm), and your END time is 5am, that means it's 5am TOMORROW, so you've done `Aug 8 10pm minus Aug 9 5am`, which gives you -16 hours

Comment: Please can you post this as an Answer with the fix code ? I am not sure about how to fix it.

Comment: @MarcB :  That is not and accurate description of the error - the dates are the same for both values - 1 Jan 1970. That is the problem, the second time needs 24 hours added if it is earlier in the day.

Comment: @Clifford are you suggesting that there is a better way of codding this Program ? If so could you please edit your Answer with the whole code ?

Comment: @Michi : Not at all, I was merely pointing out that Marc's comment dis not accurately describe the issue, and did not theerfore point to the solution.  As you have commented he should have posted an answer, rather then trying to answer in a comment.  That said; I do have a suggestion for simplification I will add to my answer.

Comment: @Clifford: typo in my comment, should've been `aug 8 5am`.

Comment: @MarcB : Another reason for posting an answer - they can be edited and corrected indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `end` is after midnight and `start` before, add 24 hours to the `end` value:

```
if( end < start )
{
    end += 24 * 60 * 60 ;
}
diff = difftime(end, start);
```

Note too that all the code related to mktime and tm struct is unnecessary.  Those are useful when you require *time normalisation* (for example if you set tm_hour to 25, mktime will generate a time_t value that is 0100hrs the following day, rolling over the month and year too if necessary), but here you are dealing with just time of day in hours and minutes, so you need just:

```
int hour ;
int minute ; 

if((scanf("%d:%d", &hour, &minute)) != 2){
    return 1;
}

start = (time_t)((hour * 60 + minute) * 60) ;

printf("End time (HH:MM): ");

if((scanf("%d:%d", &hour, &minute)) != 2){
    return 1;
}
end = (time_t)((hour * 60 + minute) * 60) ;
```

Comment: i am feeling my self just like i am...as a beginner. I should notice that.